# How Does Celery AsyncResult Function Know Which Broker or Backend to Query?

Tags: python, redis, celery, task, messagebroker

This is how I am sending a task to the celery workers and capturing the resulting task id. The `app` variable, i.e. the celery app, has the redis broker and backend url set as part of its properties. This is working fine.

```py
from celery import Celery
REDIS_BROKER:str='redis://127.0.0.1:6369'
app: Celery = Celery(backend=REDIS_BROKER, broker=REDIS_BROKER)
task: str = app.send_task(name='add_two_numbers',
                                      args=[28, 93]).id
# task='574b72ad-4512-4e0b-a14b-f56a2f725374' # An example
```

When I check the task status and result, this also works, when I thought it should not (which is why I am asking the question).

```py
from celery.result import AsyncResult
status: str = AsyncResult(id='574b72ad-4512-4e0b-a14b-f56a2f725374').state
result: int = AsyncResult(id='574b72ad-4512-4e0b-a14b-f56a2f725374').result
```

My question is *why* this works? There can be any number of redis brokers running on any IP address, which is why I am supplying the socket address of the broker to the `app` variable. Should not `AsyncResult` ask for task id, broker URL and backend URL to fetch the task status/result for me?
Or does it have some kind of invisible connection with the `app` object in the script to get those broker and backend URLs?

When I look up, it seems most tutorials and answers couple django and celery together to answer the questions, but I am using celery without django, purely as a task processor without any web development component. Hence, the question.

Answer (score 1):

You must have initialised app before calling AsyncResult and using it. Celery has a `current_app` proxy variable which is resolved to the current instance of app in the current session/runtime. As you have guessed, there is some connection to the `app` instance inside `AsyncResult` through `current_app` reference.

If you ran it in a python REPL session, launch a new terminal and test. This would throw an exception of `Backend not configured properly`.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, how to get the status and result without depending on this hidden connection? I tried 
```from celery.result import AsyncResult

task='a158ce19-54dc-4d40-b6a4-b7732736537d'

status: str = AsyncResult(id=task, backend=REDIS_BROKER).state

result: int = AsyncResult(id=task, backend=REDIS_BROKER).result
```
But it throws error. Does AynchResult need the entire app or the task id and backend URL is enough? What's the minimal coupling I can use here, without depending on the ```current_app```?